# javax.ws.rs.core.Application constructor called twice

Tags: java, jax-rs, wildfly

I have a Jax-Rs application and I'm trying to understand why my application initializer is called twice.

This is the initializator:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
    private HashSet<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public JaxRsActivator() {
        CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter();
        corsFilter.getAllowedOrigins().add("*");
        corsFilter.setAllowedMethods("OPTIONS, GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH");
        singletons.add(corsFilter);
        singletons.add(new CacheManager());

        classes.add(RequestMetadataFilter.class);
        classes.add(ResponseMetadataFilter.class);

        classes.add(CommonController.class);
    }   

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }

    @Override
    public HashSet<Class<?>> getClasses(){
      return classes;
    }
}
```

And this is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>MyApp</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/error-403.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

I'm running it on Wildfly 14 with Java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think that the problem was on beans.xml and it's bean-discovery-mode set to "all" instead of "annotated".